# How do I access the customer logo in the top left in Apex?

Tags: metadata

I know that to change the customer logo in the top-left corner of the screen you need to go into Setup -> Create -> Apps.

However I am unable to find a reference to this in my Apex class.  The prefix for the 'Apps' object is '02u' but there is no 'Apps' object in the Schema in Eclipse.  Likewise, I can't see it among the Static Resources.  There is an 'applications' folder in the metadata but this just contains label and tab names.

I am aware that the logo depends on the current user but is there no place where all the customer logos are stored so that I can access them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App logos are not available in Apex, I don't think, but they are available via the SOAP (web services) API. See `logoUrl` in [describeTabSetResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describetabs_describetabsetresult.htm#topic-title).

Edit: A good link from Daniel below if you're writing Apex. If you're writing Obj-C (iOS/OSX), check out [zkSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce) and [this caching system](https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/Salesforce-for-iPad/blob/master/Accounts/util/SFVAppCache.h) I wrote for Salesforce for iPad.

Comment: I found this reference for [Calling Salesforce Web Services Using Apex](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/calling-salesforce-web-services-using-apex). Ideally you would use the active session details rather than a user name and password for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to programatically dereference the customer logo. Your best bet (if you have to do it) is to change it with DOM manipulation with JS on your custom VF pages.

The logos can be associated with Apps and managed packages via the Documents API as well, but they're very static, and once again the 'App' object isn't manipulatable via the DML layer either.