# How to extract the application brand logo image over an API?

Tags: metadata-api, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-ready

In API 38 (Winter '17), when an "App Branding" image is uploaded through the Lightning Experience UI, the app metadata includes this brand information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#AF2524</headerColor>
        <logo>CV_CF_Icon_128</logo>
        <logoVersion>1</logoVersion>
    </brand>
    ...
```

The [CustomApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customapplication.htm) documentation says that the `logo` is:

> The optional reference to the image document for the application.

But I don't see a `Document` with a matching name.

Where is this logo image stored, and how can I extract it via the metadata so I can add it to version control and have a working continuous integration deployment from that version control copy?

**PS**

Used "Search Salesforce" and found it presented as a "File" (a ContentDocument). Is there a good way to get this into version control?

Comment: Are there any clues about there the logo is stored when viewing the branding image in use? Maybe an ID in the image url.

Comment: @DanielBallinger See the PS - does appear to be a "File". Don't think the metadata API includes that so wondering what is the best way to grab the image.

Comment: You probably have to use SOAP. [How do I access the customer logo in the top left in Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/524/how-do-i-access-the-customer-logo-in-the-top-left-in-apex)

Comment: I'm sure you *could* pull the ContentVersion down via either the SOAP or REST API's. Seems like it would be a bit ugly to migrate it that way via Source Control though. How would you then stand up a new org from source alone? You would need to create the ContentVersion record and then  put the name into the logo in the metadata. Seems like a weak link. What if the logo name changes?

Comment: You could store the image in a `resources` folder alongside the `src` folder and then have your CI script [upload the logo file(s)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) during the build process. You'd just need to have this resources folder checked into your repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I checked in the app, the Ant deploy error was:

> In field: logo - no ContentAsset named CV_CF_Icon_128 found

which a quick Google then revealed this new type name to be added to package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>CV_CF_Icon_128</members>
    <name>ContentAsset</name>
</types>
```

that resulted in a folder called `contentassets` in the project with a `CV_CF_Icon_128.asset` file and a corresponding meta file of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentAsset xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <language>en_US</language>
    <masterLabel>CV_CF_Icon_128</masterLabel>
    <relationships>
        <organization>
            <access>VIEWER</access>
        </organization>
    </relationships>
    <versions>
        <version>
            <number>1</number>
            <pathOnClient>CV_CF_Icon_128.png</pathOnClient>
        </version>
    </versions>
</ContentAsset>
```

This deployed correctly in the next build.

Comment: I have same been able to deploy too by adding ContentAsset in package.xml.  However, in my target sandbox org the Image (png) doesn't show up.  I can search and find it in files and it has been deployed.  The custom lightning app displays blank whitespace for the icon.  Like it is missing.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ChristianAnderson I'm afraid I don't have any ideas - it just worked for me so I never had to look very hard at it.

Comment: The good thing is that it also supports wildcards:
       <types>
     <members>*</members>
     <name>ContentAsset</name>
 </types>

Comment: @ChristianAnderson I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: This helped a lot, but I needed to have all 3 of these metadata types included in the package for the branding theme to deploy and show up in the lists:
1) BrandingSet
2) ContentAsset
3) LightningExperienceTheme


<types>
 <name>BrandingSet</name>
 <members>LEXTHEMINGMyBrandingName</members>
</types>
<types>
 <name>ContentAsset</name>
 <members>Brand_Logo</members>
</types>
<types>
 <name>LightningExperienceTheme</name>
 <members>MyBrandingName</members>
</types>

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer from Keith C:

After modifying package.xml, it was necessary to right click the project folder and click "Force.com" > "Refresh from Server" in order to generate the folder and file.