# Deploy Custom App Icon using Package.xml

Tags: salesfoce, custom-app

Hi Team I am trying to deploy a custom App to the new Dev Org . My App Got deployed but the custom logo is showing as blank.

Can anyone help here?

Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    
    <types>
        <members>CustomApp</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContentAsset</name>
    </types>
    
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Custom Application Meta

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>Task_Record_Page</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType>Task__c</pageOrSobjectType>
    </actionOverrides>
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#029944</headerColor>
        <logo>X6955209128_21</logo>
        <logoVersion>1</logoVersion>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>true</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <description>Custom App </description>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>true</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>true</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <label>CustomApp</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <profileActionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <profile>Admin</profile>
    </profileActionOverrides>
    <tabs>standard-home</tabs>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
</CustomApplication>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the application meta file which you pushed, also cross verify name of image you added. Ref - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151384/how-to-extract-the-application-brand-logo-image-over-an-api

Comment: @YsrShk I updated my question with application meta

Comment: Did you check the name of contentasset, permission and path. Same is mentioned in above link.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly I just Log out and log in again after sometime and everything i want it there. Don't know why it didn't reflect immediately after deployment

Thanks @Ysr Shk for Following this to help me